# Pandas finding occurrences of a specific value across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count

I want to find the number of ids under a specific time that have a value of 0.
My df looks like this:

```
    datetime          id          value        other_info
   05/01/12:00       001            1              n/a
   05/01/12:00       001            0              n/a
   05/01/12:30       001            1              n/a
   05/01/12:00       002            0              n/a
   05/01/12:30       002            0              n/a
```

My intended output would be:

```
   datetime          id          zero_count
   05/01/12:00       001            1
   05/01/12:00       002            1
   05/01/12:30       002            1
```

I thought grouping by time and then id and then running count where value equals 0 would work, but it is giving me the number of 0s across the whole dataframe instead of the number of 0s that correspond to the datetime and id.

I'm fairly new to pandas, so I don't know if there is something built in that could help me. I would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter your data then groupby:

```
(df[df['value']==0].groupby(['datetime','id']).size()
    .reset_index(name='zero_count')
)
```

Output:

```
      datetime  id  zero_count
0  05/01/12:00   1           1
1  05/01/12:00   2           1
2  05/01/12:30   2           1
```

Comment: Do you know why I would be getting an empty df with this? I can that I have zero values but it only returns the 3 column headers.

Comment: is your `value` column numerical or string type? you may need to change `==0` into `=='0'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
s=df.value.eq(0).astype(int).groupby([df.datetime,df.id]).sum().reset_index()
      datetime  id  value
0  05/01/12:00   1      1
1  05/01/12:00   2      1
2  05/01/12:30   1      0
3  05/01/12:30   2      1
```